# I have a new Kenwood TH-F6A, Mac computer and am new to our hobby. How do I program it?

Tags: kenwood, radio-programming

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use an open source software called CHIRP: http://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home

The software will work for your radio. It is fairly universally used and not that difficult to learn.